# Overriding setArguments() in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know the recommended way of passing parameters to Fragments is to use a static method and create a bundle and call setArguments()/getArguments() on the Fragment:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int arg1, int arg2) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt("key1", arg1);
    b.putInt("key2", arg2);
    MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();
    frag.setArguments(b);
}

public View onCreateView(....) {
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    memberVar1 = b.getInt("key1");
    memberVar2 = b.getInt("key2");
    .....
}
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems like the following approach works as well, which doesn't require calling getArguments() later on:

```
@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    memberVar1 = args.getInt("key1");
    memberVar2 = args.getInt("key2");
}
```

This is based on the way that setArguments() is implemented in the Fragment class. If this allows mArguments to be accessed in the event of Fragment recreation, then shouldn't the same apply to other variables set within the setArguments() call?

```
659     public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
660         if (mIndex >= 0) {
661             throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment already active");
662         }
663         mArguments = args;
664     }
```

Aside from convention, does either scenario have an advantage over the other?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a reason for you to have to override the `setArguments(...)` method... Here is a possible approach for you to take to 'cleanup' the arguments passing.

Create a new class, something like `MyFragmentArguments.java`.

```
public class MyFragmentArguments {
public long keyOne;
public long keyTwo;

public MyFragmentArguments(long keyOne, long keyTwo) {
    this.keyOne = keyOne;
    this.keyTwo = keyTwo;
}

public MyFragmentArguments(Bundle bundle) {
    this.keyOne = bundle.getLong("KEY_ONE");
    this.keyTwo = bundle.getLong("KEY_TWO");
}

public Bundle toBundle() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putLong("KEY_ONE", keyOne);
    args.putLong("KEY_TWO", keyTwo);

    return args;
}
```

}

Then, you can (very cleanly) call:

```
final MyFragmentArguments arguments = new MyFragmentArguments (getArguments());

if(arguments != null) { 
    // do something with arguments.keyOne & arguments.keyTwo
}
```

This way, you avoid unintended side effects of overriding something that's built into the android OS - something that you should strongly question whenever you do.

Comment: My question wasn't as much about cleanliness as it was about consequences. I was wondering if anyone knew the unintended side effects of overriding the method, which I understand can be a difficult question to answer.

Comment: There aren't really any consequences as long as you're making sure to follow the original intent of the method `setArguments`. The real point I'm trying to get across is that you shouldn't have to override it to achieve what you're trying to do. Also, overriding `setArguments` in the manner that you're proposing does violate SOLID principles - changes to the callers of setArguments can result in the need to change the base method, which can cause a chain reaction of unintended consequences.

Answer (score -1):

Once you call the super implementation of setArguments you maintain the integrity of the pattern.